# How to include condition in PXProcessingJoin for Where clause

Tags: acumatica

I have to develop a processing page. However, I want to filter the grid based on some attributes. Not sure how to include that. Can anyone suggest.

Here is the code. ?? is the place where I want to include the attribute such as CaseNo.

```html
[PXFilterable]
        public PXProcessingJoin<CRCase,
            LeftJoin<BAccount, On<CRCase.customerID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>,
            LeftJoin<CREmployee, On<CRCase.ownerID, Equal<CREmployee.userID>>,
            LeftJoin<CSAnswers, On<CRCase.noteID, Equal<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>>>>,
            Where<CRCase.majorStatus, NotEqual<CRCaseMajorStatusesAttribute.closed>, 
                And<CRCase.majorStatus, NotEqual<CRCaseMajorStatusesAttribute.released>,
                And<CSAnswers.value, IsNotNull,
                And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<??>>>>>,
            OrderBy<Desc<CRCase.caseCD>>> ProcessCase;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'some attributes'. Is it hardcoded values? Is it values from filter? Is it something else?

Comment: It is a hardcode values.

Comment: In this case you have to create BQL constant.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use BQL constant. Like that:

```
public class decimal_100 : Constant<Decimal>
{
    public decimal_100(): base(100m)
    { }
}
```

After that you can use this constant in the BQL, like that:

```
PXSelect<ARInvoice, Where<ARInvoice.CuryOrigDocAmount, Equal<decimal_100>>>
```

Please check T200 training example 3.1 for more information.
You can also take a look at ARDocType.invoice class.